# Modify an object between two files

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am developing a nodejs project and stuck at this problem.
I have an empty object in one file and will update this object value in a secondf ile.

jsonFile.js

```
var jsonObj = {



    first: []

    ,
    second: []


    ,
    third: [],
};


exports.jsonObj=jsonObj;
```

pushdata.js

```
 var obj= require('./jsonFile.js');
 // i'll retrieve data from file and push into the obj...
 // for the sake of simplicity im not writing data fetching code..

ojb.jsonObj.first.push("user1");
```

How can I update this object in **pushdata.js** file in such a way that it also updates/change the object in **jsonFile.js**

Comment: What you have is a JavaScript object. [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). Nothing in your example has anything to do with JSON.

Comment: thanks for your response. How can i update this javascript object from pushdata.js file?

Comment: What you have will just work. Objects are passed around as references. There is only a single object.

Comment: If this is on the server likely you're going to want to use the fs module to update the file. However it is unclear if we are dealing with the client or server in your example.

Comment: Sorry for unclearance. I am developing a api and http server is used. How can I solve this problem with fs module?

Comment: I was busy writing an answer based on the fs module, have a look below

Comment: see user carlos13's answer this would be the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to handle this is to do the following:

1. Change jsonFile.js to a .json file (you can still require it as you have)
2. Update it as you have e.g. ojb.jsonObj.first.push("user1");
3. Write the changes to the file system.

Here's a code example:

**jsonFile.json**

```
{
    "first": [],
    "second": [],
    "third": []
}
```

**pushdata.js**

```
        var fs = require('fs');
        var obj = require('./jsonFile.json');
        ojb.first.push("user1");
        fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + '/jsonFile.json', JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4), 'utf8');
```

Using writeFileSync for simplicity but best to do file system writes using async functionality to avoid blocking code.

Comment: Sorry could you clarify what you mean? Is the above not what you expected?

Comment: I was expecting this. Now its clear to me. Thanks you solved my problem :)

Answer (score 2):

you cant' update jsonFile.js file this way, because require create instance 
every time when call require()
if you want to update the file, you need to create json data file,
read that json file using fs module and convert into javascript object and update javascript object and then use JSON.stringfy to convert string and then write file using fs module.

OR 
you can create service in nodeJS for sharing data between modules